# how to connect to a secured ms access database via vb.net using oledb

Tags: vb.net, oledb, ms-access-2010

I have a database database1.mdb created in ms access 10.

I opened it in exclusive mode and set the password to abcd12.
I am using vb.net to INSERT data & DELETE data from that database but somehow it is not able to connect.  Any ideas why connection cant be made?

```
Dim FilePath As String = "C:\Users\johnny\database1.mdb"
dbconn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" & _ 
FilePath & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=abcd12;")
```

Insert statement below:

```
dbconn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" & FilePath & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=abcd12;")
    Try
        dbconn.Open()
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO myTable ([col1],[col2],[col3],[col4],[col5]) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
        objcmd = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, dbconn)

        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@col1", "user12345"))    
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@col2", "user2345"))
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@col3", "user3456"))
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@col4", "user4567"))       
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@col5", "user5678"))
        objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        dbconn.Close()
    Catch myException As System.Exception
        Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(myException.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Please confirm that you can login to the MDB (with the same credentials as vb.net) and you can make changes (insert, delete).

Comment: What are the error messages you get?  Post those in your question.

Comment: Rule of thumb when you write a question on SO: always provide all the exception details you can.

Comment: this time i could connect to the database but the insert queries dont work..like they used to before i had secured the database with password..what to do??

Comment: what do you mean by "the insert queries dont work". Is it executing but not updating or is it an unhandled exception (error)

Comment: it is executing but not really insertiing data

Comment: If it's executing then that means that there's no exception, right?  What value is returned by ExecuteNonQuery?  If that's not zero then data is being inserted.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns an integer of the rows affected so assign in to an integer variable and when the statement executed then check that variable. - also i think (not too sure of the syntax) but your values should all have a single quote around them if they are strings. ie VALUES ('string1','string2')